# Flutter multiple `MaterialApp` lead to conflict

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

two MaterialApp lead to navigator occur error, because I can only modify outermost layer MaterialApp ,  I remove outermost layer MaterialApp, it tell me 'MediaQuery.of() called with a context that does not contain a MediaQuery.'   What can I do ?

```
return MaterialApp(
  navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
  home: Scaffold(
    body: Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.center, 
      children: [
        RepaintBoundary(
          child: child,
          key: rootKey,
        ),
        _ContentPage()
      ]
    )
  )
);
```

Comment: Why has your inner element it's own MaterialApp and why is it that you cannot modify it?

Comment: because it is the other side of the business, I wrote the plugin，can i remove navigator ?